# Cannot open TIF files using TauDEM in ArcMap:

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, geotiff-tiff, taudem

I am trying to use TauDEM in Arcmap.
When I try to start the "Pit Remove" script it does not accept my .tif Input (see picture).
Same with every other script from the tbx. 
If I press OK a empty error messagebox occurs.

[image: Error TauDEM]

Any idea ?

Comment: Whats the error message when you hover over the red cross? Also you need to state which versions you are using.

Comment: There is no tooltip when I hover over the Red Cross :/. ArcMap 10.5 / latest TauDEM Version from website, Py2.7

Comment: You are not telling full story. You also changed output default name and number of processes.